# How to create a new GraphServiceClient by AccessToken value?

Tags: charts

Is anyone here good at Graph SDK Java?

Is there a way for me to create a GraphServiceClient from a valid accesssToken?

My problem is that I need to save the accesssToken so that when the client authenticates to my API application, I can use the accesssToken to recreate a GraphServiceClient without having to re-authenticate with Microsoft.

If there is a way to solve the problem in any way, please share it. Thank you